# Is web browser JavaScript runtime?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

In [Node.js website](https://nodejs.org/en/), they say Node.js is a JavaScript **runtime**.

Are web browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Edge, ... JavaScript runtimes?

I thought of course, web browser is JS runtime. But I'm confused, In [this video 12:10~](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=147&v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) He says Web browser is not just JavaScript runtime because it can do more things 
 at one time, it can give us other things.

But I think V8 engine only can do one thing at one time, while JS runtime can do more things than one at one time.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Web browsers *usually* **include** a JS Engine.

Comment: JS *code* (i.e. the stuff you write and the libraries you use etc) only does one thing at a time, this is also true in nodejs!! ... However, the underlying JS **engine** is not restricted in this way - which is how "asynchronous" methods can work

Comment: @JaromandaX Hmm, I thought engines WERE single-threaded. Or else you're using the term "at a time" in a slightly non-intuitive way.

Comment: "I thought of course, web browser is JS runtime." I can't imagine why you would have "of course" thought that. Who did you think is painting the pixels on the screen?

Comment: @torazaburo While engines *might* be single-threaded, most common ones nowadays are not. If you take v8 for instance, it will start one thread for the JIT, one for profiling so that Crankshaft can optimize, and a few for GC.

Comment: engines threadedness has no bearing on how javascript is "processed" by the engine ... javascript code is not "any threaded" - it's  ... well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: @user9349950 JavaScript as of now has two runtimes available for it - Browsers & NodeJS. JavaScript engines are part of the browser runtime

Answer (score 6):

A browser contains a Javascript engine (for example Chrome v8). The engine implements a Javascript runtime, which includes the call stack, heap and event loop. The browser also usually includes a set of APIs that augment the Javascript runtime and make asynchronous code execution possible. 
NodeJS also implements a Javascript runtime using Chrome's v8 engine as well as the Libuv library (event loop and worker threads).

Here's a good video that breaks this all down:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xsvn6VUTwQ

Comment: Does JavaScript engine include event loop? This guys is saying that V8 source code doesn't contain event loop. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=466s

Answer (score 2):

They are right, a JavaScript runtime just executes the JavaScript code.

All Web browsers include a JavaScript runtime engine(RE) that executes js code for them but they also have other plugins like java or flash, as well as an html/dom parser and renderers that are not part of the RE, even if those modules were written in JavaScript it does not mean they would be part of the RE.

Comment: You are probably confusing *runtime* and *Engine*. You can have several runtimes ran by the same engine, in concurrence. Also, all browsers don't have a js engine (and hence won't start any js runtime), e.g Lynx doesn't.

Comment: @Kalido In what kinds of scenarios would one engine have multiple runtimes? Are you talking about web workers? Or iframes?

Comment: @torazaburo I guess it depends on the implementations, but IIRC in FF a new tab will create a new run-time. Workers would too, for iframe I don't think so.